Sign change in the proof of the scaling property of the Dirac delta function
In order to prove the scaling property of the Dirac delta function
$$\delta(bt)=\frac{1}{|b|}\delta(t)$$
here's what a book I have does for the case $b < 0$.

A substitution $t' = -ct$ has been done, so $t = -t'/c$, $bt = t'$, and $dt = -dt'/c$. Plugging in the results, why does the sign change to negative (swapping the integration limits) in the middle part of the first line?

because $\int_a^b=-\int_b^a$

@Surb I know, so where does the minus come from?

where ? $ \ \ \ \ \ $

@Surb As I wrote in the question, the part where the integration limits swap is same as the sign changing to negative, and I don't understand why the sign should change after substitution.

Let's look at a general case of how the substitution $x=-y$ works.
In a first step limits and the differential change sign:
$$
\int_{a}^{b} f(x) \, dx
= \int_{-a}^{-b} f(-y) \, (-dy)
= \cdots
$$
Then we can move the negative sign in front of the integral and use it to swap the limits of the integral:
$$
\cdots
= -\int_{-a}^{-b} f(-y) \, dy
= \int_{-b}^{-a} f(-y) \, dy.
$$
Now take $a=-\infty,\ b=\infty$ and you get
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \, dx
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(-y) \, dy.
$$
